# puppet - exec command in virtualenv context

Tags: django, virtualenv, puppet, provisioning

I am building a vagrant box that is provisioned by puppet. 
The main purpose of this box is Python development. To be consistent with non-vagrant development environments I want to use a virtualenv to handle my python environment.

I would like to use puppet to execute a few commands like `pip install` in my virtualenv context.

I can install a virtual environment, but I don't know how to switch into it. Is it even possible? I know that a virtual env runs inside a shell and therefore uses its context, while puppet doesn't work that way.

In case this approach doesn't seem very likely to work: What is a better approach to provision a virtual environment?

Answer (score 1):

[Python puppet module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/stankevich/python) might be a good starting point here.